# Is there a way to maintain a db relationship (pk/fk) in the following scenario

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, database-design, foreign-keys

My current db design is in the screenshot. It seems flawed because there is no enforced relationship (pk/fk) between the t_criteria_director and the t_criteria_a b c d e f... tables.  Is there a better way to design this one to many scenario to keep referential integrity?

[image: Proposed DB Design]

Comment: it seems to me you want a standard one-to-many relationship to a table with only value_a mandatory and possibly other integrity constraints. Otherwise you can always "simulate" one-to-many relationships to force FK constraints, though one-to-one relationships tend to be tedious and fragmenting.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)--in this case, for all the content of this diagram.

Comment: Thanks for info, I learned something new today. Next post I will not add an image.

Comment: Are the relationships between criteria director and the various criteria tables IS-A type relationships?  You haven't described the subject matter you are trying to model.

Answer (score 1):

Your design doesn't "seem" anything because we can't read your mind. You have given some aspects of a design but not the business "scenario" it represents/implements/describes or how it does so.

SQL NULL, UNIQUE, PKs & FKs are kinds of constraints. A constraint is a limitation on what database values can appear. An SQL FK says subrow values for a column list in a table must appear elsewhere for a column list whose columns form a SQL UNIQUE NOT NULL column set (which PK is a case of) in their table. If your design is subject to a constraint and it isn't implied by other enforced constraints, enforce it. Otherwise don't. Preferably declaratively. Most SQL DBMSs only let you declare a few kinds of cheap-to-enforce constraints. Others must be enforced via triggers.

The constraints are a consequence of the criteria for rows going into vs staying out of tables in a given situation (the table *predicates*, "what the tables mean") and what situations can & can't arise according to your business rules. We don't know what those are unless you tell us. We can hope to guess using your table & column names, any other info you give & common sense.

*You* have to tell *us* either the constraints or the predicates & what situations can/can't arise.

Here your tables are using a straightforward table plus some EAV design to record the data of some straightforward table not explicitly in your design. As always you *could* avoid EAV by just using DDL to keep the straightforward table's schema & constraints up to date, but instead you have chosen a static schema that requires more complex schema, queries & constraints. The straightforward expression of the EAV constraints is typically that the straightforward table they represent has certain constraints plus that the t_criteria_x are views of it and/or that it is a view of them. But typically the only SQL declarations available just let you express fragments of that.

I *guess* that what you intend here includes that for each t_criteria_x table its PK value must appear in t_criteria_director with a table_name value 't_criteria_x'. Another way to put this is that if you added to t_criteria_x a table_name column with value 't_criteria_x' then the result must have (id, table_name) subrows appear as t_criteria_director (criteria_id, table_name) subrows. If *also* t_criteria_director (criteria_id, table_name) subrows are SQL UNIQUE NOT NULL then we have that that augmented t_criteria_x has a composite SQL FK (id, table_name) referencing t_criteria_director (criteria_id, table_name). You can express this declaratively by actually augmenting t_criteria_x by such a (possibly computed/generated/calculated) columns. But you probably also have other constraints, like there aren't any (constraint_id, table_name) pairs in t_criteria_director that aren't referenced by some augmented t_constraint_x.

Calling the column table_name shows an implementation-oriented bias from the EAV because that column is a *type/variant discriminator/tag* in the ER sense that the types of entities represented by the ids in the t_criteria_x tables are "subtypes" of the type of entity represented by t_criteria_director. (This is also a concept/technique from 3GL record data structures used for dynamically simulating typing.) After all the table_name column value doesn't have to be a table name, it just has to be some value that identifies the entity subtype, and such entities don't have to only participate in one table's relationship/association. (Research SQL/database/ER subtyping/polymorphism/inheritance and the design anti-pattern two/many/multiple FKs [sic] to two/many/multiple tables.)

You have to determine what the table predicates are and what their constraints consequently are. Preferably via determining what the straightforward table they collectively represent is & what its predicate is and what the database constraints are using it. Then you must decide whether per cost/benefit you are going to modify your design to make constraints declarative and/or you are or are not going to enforce constraints via triggers.

Comment: I have decided to use ONE criteria table that will contain a json field and therefore I will not need potentially hundreds of criteria_a,b,c... tables.  In this particular case this works perfectly because none of those fields will need to be queried.

Comment: If you ever do have some aribtrarily deep tree-structure relationship(s) and want to generically/relationally query its parts (eg if you started with JSON data of arbitrary depth), read about CTE queries & [heirarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/3404097).