# DB schema for a resource-based messaging system

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-design, eloquent, relational-database

My laravel application has some `services and products`, for simplicity's sake, I will keep it as generic as possible and I am going to call an individual service/product a `resource`.

I will have to implement a messaging system in such a way, so that a client can send message to the admin (and vice versa) against a single `resource`.

For example, consider `project` as being one such resource. An admin can create a `project`, a client can send messages to the admin who created that project. A client cannot create a `project`.

This is how I designed the db schema:

#### Message Storing Part:

> conversations(id, message_id, from, to, body, is_seen)
>
> messages(id, resource_id, resource_name)

#### Resource Storing Part:

> projects(id, admin_id, client_id, some_other_column)
>
> another_resource(id, admin_id, client_id, some_other_column)
>
> yet_another_resource(id, admin_id, client_id, some_other_column)

Notice the `resource_id` and `resource_name` in the `messages` table:
<kbd>resource_id</kbd> is the id from one of the resource tables (projects, another_resource, yet_another_resource).
<kbd>resource_name</kbd> is where my problem is. If I implement this schema, I would have to hardcode a tablename in this column. An entry in the messages table would look like this:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | resource_name | resource_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | project       |           1 | 2018-01-13 15:11:07 | 2018-01-13 15:11:07 |
+----+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, if some client had to send a message on an entry of `another_resource` I would have to store the string `"another_resource"` as the <kbd>resource_name</kbd> in messages table and the `id` of that row of `another_resource` as the <kbd>resource_id</kbd>

---

I admit that I am not a good db designer but I have a strong feeling that storing a tablename as a column value is not a good idea. There must be some dynamic way of handling it. How could I improve my schema? Any modification, suggestion or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you have table that could share different resources (models), in your case messages, it could be set as [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are super- and subtype relationships in ER diagrams represented as tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032348/how-are-super-and-subtype-relationships-in-er-diagrams-represented-as-tables)

Comment: This is faq. Google my comments re sql/database subtyping. Google my comments re googling many variations of your question. [Re storing table names.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47725225/3404097)

Comment: Multiple tables with nearly identical columns should be the same table.  (Probably with an extra column to distinguish them.)

Comment: Thank you all. @Tpojka your suggestion worked. Actually polymorphic relation is probably the best solution for situations like this

Comment: I used it on project recently and it is really easy to access all of data you need. Also, take a look in code: docs show just morphMany relation, but you can set morphOne or even morphPivot [if needed](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphMany.html).